# HiveContext in Spark Version 2

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am working on a spark program that inserts dataframe into Hive Table as below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val hiveCont =  val hiveCont = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val partfile = sc.textFile("partfile")
val partdata = partfile.map(p => p.split(","))
case class partc(id:Int, name:String, salary:Int, dept:String, location:String)
val partRDD  = partdata.map(p => partc(p(0).toInt, p(1), p(2).toInt, p(3), p(4)))
val partDF   = partRDD.toDF()
partDF.registerTempTable("party")
hiveCont.sql("insert into parttab select id, name, salary, dept from party")
```

I know that Spark V2 has come out and we can use SparkSession object in it.
Can we use SparkSession object to directly insert the dataframe into Hive table or do we have to use the HiveContext in version 2 also ? Can anyone let me know what is the major difference in version with respect to HiveContext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `SparkSession` (normally called `spark` or `ss`) directly to fire a sql query (make sure hive-support is enabled when creating the spark-session):

```
spark.sql("insert into parttab select id, name, salary, dept from party")
```

But I would suggest this notation, you don't need to create a temp-table etc:

```
partDF
.select("id","name","salary","dept")
.write.mode("overwrite")
.insertInto("parttab")
```

Comment: Oh !
So from Spark version-2x, I can directly use the sparkSession object to insert a dataframe into an existing Hive table. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Sidhartha Yes, `SparkSession` is the main entry point for everything, `HiveContext` and `SqlContext` are not needed anymore

Comment: @Raphael Roth     I read that outside the spark-shell we need to still make the distinguishment. But perhaps that is 1.6 only I think now. So I presume we cannot have the same names for a Hive table and tempview.

Comment: But is there not a difference between insert into via SQL and overwite?

Comment: @thebluephantom I don't know. For Dataframe API the default is tho throw an exception if there is already data, alternatively you can chose append or overwrite. For spark SQL there is a INSERT OVERWRITE, so I guess this is not the default (https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/insert.html)

Comment: Just checking: for spark-submit the hivecontext is also no longer req'd? That is my understanding.